# undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass when importing Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to import Bootstrap into my rails app and I'm not quite sure what's going wrong. I've had it working before, but I did a 'bundle update' and destroyed some dependencies (I think). I've seemingly fixed everything... except for Bootstrap.

I've tried removing and re-entering the 'bootstrap-sass' gem... I can't really figure out where the error is.

Thanks for the help!

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'

group :development, :test do

  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'
end

gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner.git
  revision: 35bd646903fc56af185a9fa9e360c568bb56756e
  specs:
    database_cleaner (1.2.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.1)
      activemodel (= 4.0.1)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    arel (4.0.2)
    atomic (1.1.15)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
    bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.0)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.1.4)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    childprocess (0.5.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.1.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.9.3)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.9.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.1)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    pg (0.15.1)
    polyglot (0.3.4)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      activerecord (= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.1)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.1)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec-core (2.14.8)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
    rspec-rails (2.14.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.9)
    sass (3.3.2)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
      childprocess (>= 0.2.5)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rubyzip (< 1.0.0)
      websocket (~> 1.0.4)
    sprockets (2.12.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.8)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.2.0)
      atomic (>= 1.1.7, < 2)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.1.1)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.39)
    uglifier (2.1.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    websocket (1.0.7)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt-ruby (= 3.1.2)
  bootstrap-sass
  capybara (= 2.1.0)
  coffee-rails (= 4.0.1)
  database_cleaner!
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.2.1)
  faker (= 1.1.2)
  jbuilder (= 1.0.2)
  jquery-rails (= 3.0.4)
  pg (= 0.15.1)
  rails (= 4.0.1)
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails
  sdoc (= 0.3.20)
  selenium-webdriver (= 2.35.1)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.8)
  turbolinks (= 1.1.1)
  uglifier (= 2.1.1)
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Also, when are you seeing this error? Starting development server?

Comment: I can start the development server. I get this error when attempting to access a page on the server. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am seeing the error as well. I had a clean install with a clean Gemfile. So bundle update may not be the issue here.

Comment: Hmm. What else could be tested?

Comment: Very strange; this just started happening to me too. Is it trying to @import from somewhere that went offline?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue even without @import. Simply renaming the file application.css.scss throws me the same exception.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I ran in to this problem as well and it looks like an issue related to the latest version of sprockets and you can fix it as suggested by changing the Gemfile.lock, but if someone or something does a bundle update it's going to get broken again and I know some places don't like to check in Gemfile.lock until there's a push to stage.

If you use sass-rails better than 4.0.0 it will resolve the problem...

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

The problem is solved and it will limit sprockets to 2.11.  From the generated Gemfile.lock...

```
    sass-rails (4.0.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
```

Comment: I use sass-rails (4.0.1) and it doesn't limit sprockets-rails to 2.11.0. I had to do it manually.

Comment: @Albert have you tried sass-rails 4.0.2?  See https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/540

Comment: @JaredBeck Now I do. But I solved the original problem by setting sprockets to 2.11.0 myself.

Comment: Yes, you should use "~> 4.0.2" instead: `gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'`.

Comment: You should keep up to date on your dependencies. `sass-rails` is at 4.0.3 at the time of writing.

Answer (score 36):

I ran into this exact problem today and managed to solve it.

Funny thing is that yesterday everything was fine (of which I have proof because I pushed a working version to Heroku before going to bed last night), but today things broke after I did `bundle update`. So I went through the terminal output of that and noticed that the sprockets gem updated to 2.12.0. I then went back and realized that it was 2.11.0 yesterday. Hmm...

On a hunch, I edited my gemfile and added this line:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
```

Basically, to force bundler to install that specific version. I then did another `bundle update` and voila! Things started working again.

Comment: the solution for me was the sprockets version, not the sass-rails, many thanks!

Comment: @mat_jack1 yes but the new sass-rails also pins down sprockets to this exact same version, so that should have worked too…

Comment: that's true @AttilaO. but at the time of posting was not :)

Comment: And as an appreciator of amusing Stack Overflow usernames, I'd like to point out that "enraged camel" is a pretty good one. Almost as good as raviolicode.

Answer (score 28):

I updated my project to rails 4.0.4 yesterday and was receiving the same error. Running 'bundle update' did nothing for me. uninstalling and in reinstalling sass-rails only installed version 4.0.1. I had to change my Gemfile from:

```
gem 'sass-rails'
```

to:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
```

Then, after running 'bundle update', rspec now works as it should.

Comment: Same happened when updating to 4.0.5, using sass-rails 4.0.2 fixes the problem

Answer (score 7):

It was a gem version conflict.

Please use

`gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'`

instead of

`gem 'sass-rails'`

Perform `bundle update` right after that. That should fix it

Comment: Rails 4.0.4 caused this to happen for me.  A simple bundle update rails didn't fix it but a bundle update did (after setting rails to 4.0.4).

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this issue, after updating `sass` to 3.3.3 and `sprockets` to 2.12.0.

I ran a `$ bundle outdated` to check for which gems were outdated, and indeed `sass-rails` was included:

```
* sass-rails (4.0.2 > 4.0.1)
```

Using `$ bundle update sass-rails` solved it for me.

If you use `$ bundle update` instead, it would also solve the issue but will update other non-version-constrained gems too. Updating your gems one by one is more time-consuming, but is more useful for diagnosing the gem conflict.