# Action Controller: Exception Caught - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am observing the following error while running my localhost - [NoMethodError](https://www.dropbox.com/s/02cx8fr3ip649bm/NoMethodError.jpg)

Upon searching the problem, I identified it could be due to the SASS & Coffee gems listed in my gem file as shown below:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
```

By disabling them, I ran bundle update successfully and restarted the rails server. However, I am still seeing the same error.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: It seems that this Q/A is similar to yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392862/undefined-method-environment-for-nilnilclass-when-importing-bootstrap

Comment: @JérémieOnRails, I have already checked the solution and applied it as per my description in the question. This hasn't helped.

Comment: Looks like it could be inside your `application.css.sass`? Have you got anything in there which could be causing a problem?

Comment: @RichPeck, the only line in my `application.css.sass` is `@import 'custom'`. Nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried without that line?

Comment: @RichPeck, yes. I have tried without the line and it works. But the CSS styling does not take into effect. I am trying to understand as to why this is causing an issue. None of my other collaborators seem to be having this issue.

Comment: @RichPeck, in addition to that, I also tried updating the 'sass-rails', 'coffee-rails' and 'sprockets-rails' gems to ensure there was no compatibility issue and I received the following errors:
[NoMethodError](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/et6obewtvqbet1x/4ZSwOdnmXH).

Comment: Hi Everyone, looks like the problem got fixed by limiting the sprockets gem to 2.11.0. Not sure why it did not work previously, but it seems fine now.