# Not pushing to heroku after mergin branch and bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I made several changes, and tried to push to heroku, but it crashed and gave me an error with debugger gem , which I searched in stack overflow.

I did bundle update to fix it (as people said), and removed debugger from the gemfile. But now, It will give another error, and will not push or compile assets.

The error is:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass
```

Its so strange, because it's reinstalling every gem in Heroku, as well as compiling assets as if it was the first time. Please help, I can't push the new feature! Thanks a lot

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 2.0.0p576 (2014-09-19 revision 47628) [x86_64-linux]
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
       Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
       Installing minitest 4.7.5
       Installing i18n 0.6.11
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Installing builder 3.1.4
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing tzinfo 0.3.41
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing rack 1.5.2
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing execjs 2.2.1
       Installing sass 3.4.4
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing arel 4.0.2
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing acts_as_votable 0.8.0
       Installing coderay 1.1.0
       Installing daemons 1.1.9
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.7
       Installing multipart-post 2.0.0
       Installing formatador 0.2.5
       Installing excon 0.39.5
       Installing inflecto 0.0.2
       Installing ipaddress 0.8.0
       Installing mini_portile 0.6.0
       Installing net-ssh 2.9.1
       Installing hashie 3.3.1
       Installing jwt 1.0.0
       Installing method_source 0.8.2
       Installing subexec 0.2.3
       Installing multi_xml 0.5.5
       Installing nifty-generators 0.4.6
       Installing httpclient 2.4.0
       Installing slop 3.6.0
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.2
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
       Installing eventmachine 1.0.3
       Installing rolify 3.4.1
       Installing will_paginate 3.0.7
       Installing faker 1.3.0
       Installing fog-json 1.0.0
       Installing sitemap_generator 5.0.5
       Installing activesupport 4.0.0
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing pg 0.17.1
       Installing warden 1.2.3
       Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
       Installing treetop 1.4.15
       Installing bourbon 4.0.2
       Installing sprockets 2.12.2
       Installing haml 4.0.5
       Installing zurb-foundation 4.3.2
       Installing rdoc 4.1.2
       Installing uglifier 2.5.3
       Installing faraday 0.9.0
       Installing mandrill-api 1.0.52
       Installing net-scp 1.2.1
       Installing omniauth 1.2.2
       Installing mini_magick 3.8.1
       Installing pry 0.10.1
       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2
       Installing thin 1.6.2
       Installing arbre 1.0.2
       Installing activemodel 4.0.0
       Installing jbuilder 1.5.3
       Installing actionpack 4.0.0
       Installing rmagick 2.13.3
       Installing mail 2.5.4
       Installing faraday_middleware 0.9.1
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Installing oauth2 1.0.0
       Installing activerecord 4.0.0
       Installing fog-core 1.24.0
       Installing carrierwave 0.10.0
       Installing railties 4.0.0
       Installing formtastic 2.3.1
       Installing has_scope 0.6.0.rc
       Installing kaminari 0.16.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.0.1
       Installing meta-tags 2.0.0
       Installing mandrill_mailer 0.4.8
       Installing actionmailer 4.0.0
       Installing simple_form 3.0.2
       Installing omniauth-oauth2 1.2.0
       Installing polyamorous 1.1.0
       Installing instagram 1.1.3
       Installing friendly_id 5.0.4
       Installing fog-brightbox 0.5.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Installing fog-softlayer 0.3.17
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.3.1
       Installing responders 1.0.0
       Installing jquery-ui-rails 5.0.0
       Installing jquery-rails 3.1.2
       Installing devise 3.3.0
       Installing jquery-fileupload-rails 0.4.1
       Installing mail_form 1.5.0
       Installing sass-rails 4.0.1
       Installing omniauth-facebook 2.0.0
       Installing ransack 1.3.0
       Installing rails 4.0.0
       Installing impressionist 1.5.1
       Installing best_in_place 0.2.3
       Installing inherited_resources 1.4.1
       Installing rails3-jquery-autocomplete 1.0.14
       Using activeadmin 1.0.0.pre from git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git (at master)
       Installing fog 1.23.0
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from sitemap_generator:
       NOTE: SitemapGenerator 4.x uses a new file naming scheme which is more standards-compliant.
       If you're upgrading from 3.x, please see the release note in the README:
       https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator#important-changes-in-version-4
       The simple answer is that your index file is now called sitemap.xml.gz
       and not sitemap_index.xml.gz, but please take a look and see what else has changed.
       Post-install message from haml:
       HEADS UP! Haml 4.0 has many improvements, but also has changes that may break
       your application:
       * Support for Ruby 1.8.6 dropped
       * Support for Rails 2 dropped
       * Sass filter now always outputs <style> tags
       * Data attributes are now hyphenated, not underscored
       * html2haml utility moved to the html2haml gem
       * Textile and Maruku filters moved to the haml-contrib gem
       For more info see:
       http://rubydoc.info/github/haml/haml/file/CHANGELOG.md
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Post-install message from rmagick:
       Please report any bugs. See https://github.com/gemhome/rmagick/compare/RMagick_2-13-2...master and https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues/18
       Post-install message from instagram:
       ********************************************************************************
       Instagram REST and Search APIs
       ------------------------------
       Our developer site documents all the Instagram REST and Search APIs.
       (http://instagram.com/developer)
       Blog
       ----------------------------
       ********************************************************************************
       Bundle completed (159.26s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:26.899517 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/FontAwesome-00cd9d29c16ec7755492c39df16ce1aa.otf
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:26.902231 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/decofont-452bc8caf426f1a11ab150183b3f8c7d.eot
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:26.971341 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/default-user-b1cdb481024e4a933abf2ea35c8a851f.jpg
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:26.973473 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/default-user-3beca87e6c4c2f1634205b63dd1751bc.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:26.975646 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/default-user2-3beca87e6c4c2f1634205b63dd1751bc.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:26.977951 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/divider-66feeff2926f8a3809241cc2715bb7ff.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:26.980266 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/divider_line-c574f55865acb9fd30d99d889a8d7810.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:26.982394 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/favicon-a72059f9bc87311fbe16a3feb1b3011a.ico
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.096123 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/input-checked-fad93ad02fae91846487120f3f753fe9.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.098802 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/input-unchecked-16a647a0b7e7ee068d80db470a4fe4a6.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.101028 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/landing/icon_1-a5802dd0f18b9aa07de783bba92fa6ad.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.103200 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/landing/icon_2-9942940855b7f3a6a25a803a20cdfa11.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.105372 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/landing/icon_3-758cfe433057344146ed25487f740b0e.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.107582 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/landing/icon_4-b25b74ffcaf2f5bf6a56ca3613ccf851.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.109474 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/landing/icon_pro-9c97b48cc702eb38dcfa3f792a4e92a1.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.111501 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/logo -906a3a689726de87ae1b25bef1770cf5.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.113516 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/logo-9ec2463dd9f201719cec993d96a20334.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.115924 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/logo@2x-ca7b605d7d2f819b2180110531c79a99.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.118614 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/logogrande-2dad34d8965fa9580bf732da629b3d79.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.121177 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/logogrey-17446392f18181466fec15ae77c541ce.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.123471 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/passbg-198396ac2bb01641ef1e2d0d5b8290e7.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.125871 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/search-c128d565ca441f7f56f1c0a68d80c71a.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.128238 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/searchbg-c128d565ca441f7f56f1c0a68d80c71a.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.130708 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/seed/1-2f4399488cc4461f37290f1a13ce2e26.jpg
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.133169 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/seed/2-11c83688373956e1f3be2799e553bfdb.jpg
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.135748 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/seed/3-47e462f8d6704b84257cde15ff6120a9.jpg
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.138471 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/seed/4-efc0abe95bc6656f89b367f5df4d6222.jpg
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.141336 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/seed/5-d941023eda8d263bc67c430fa7bfd7f2.jpg
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.144422 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/slider1-dd1e84fd4c642c09bdeea7995e6afe9f.jpg
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.147167 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/sp-c6070afd2f38ae891441f959b1b7a1ff.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.149543 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/spots_header-0b187e7ae03e3cd01587bd08d73c2a55.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.151929 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/tagarrow-8b84e20c18b23d6cfd12f78277de90c9.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.154300 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/tagcursor-92631a09d2f0a033c5d74a5b24e6506a.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:27.156500 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/userbg-3b8a7645bebf562e9562c8b6e9b578a2.png
       I, [2014-09-19T18:37:37.474618 #3047]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/public/assets/application-88a409f2962d296c3ea2f0ae2c57efe9.js
       rake aborted!
       NoMethodError: undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass
       (in /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-4.0.1/lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:84:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-4.0.1/lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:70:in `engine_from_path'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-4.0.1/lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:35:in `find'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:54:in `block in import'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:53:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:53:in `import'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:301:in `visit_import'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.4/lib/sass/engine.rb:268:in `render'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/sass_template.rb:53:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_0c151ed0-2c3a-484c-bfdf-a8944781130b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined method \`environment' for nil:NilClass when importing Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392862/undefined-method-environment-for-nilnilclass-when-importing-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and fixed it:

Your RVM gemset is 2.0.0p481 according to your logs. Heroku has moved on to 2.0.0p576.

You need to upgrade to the latest package of Ruby. If you're using RVM:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p576
bundle update
```

Then commit and deploy to heroku.

Comment: Still giving the error:   

 NoMethodError: undefined method `environment' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I ran `bundle update`and it said: Could not find sass-3.4.4 in any of the sources

Comment: It's difficult to tell without your Gemfile what's broken. Looks though like you're using Sass-rails v4.0.1. I'm using v4.0.3 successfully. Also consider upgrading to ruby-2.1.3 which is currently the latest.